# My desktop won't shut down. Instead it BSOD's with a driver power state failure error

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I've got an older HP Pavilion Elite desktop PC, currently running Windows 8.1 Pro. I can't shut it down gracefully, because when I try to it will wait a while and then go through a BSOD and reboot itself. The error is DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE, but it doesn't give me any error number to go off of, so I'm not sure what to do about this or how to fix it. And honestly I don't have the money to replace this older machine.

What recommendations do you suggest I do?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Usually there's no easy solution (or no solution at all) when power states won't work. 99% of the time it's a buggy driver. Since it's an older box, chances are that you don't have any driver or BIOS updates available that would be newer than what you already have. Basically you're very likely SOL.

Comment: Have you checked this link : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/81-update-driverpowerstatefailure/1472a6ae-ebe8-4940-8cfb-16e613c2f226

Comment: What you said is very discouraging, but I suspect you're correct. i.e. that my machine is too old for any updates that would help. 

I do have a .dmp file in the location you've specified. Don't know how to analyze it, though.

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\minidump, so that I can take a look at it with the debugger.